# Find $f(x)$ from two-variable equation

Tags: calculus, functions, even-and-odd-functions

Let $f$ be a function which satisfies the equation
\begin{equation}
f(x-y+a)-f(x+y+a)=2f(x)f(y)
\end{equation}
where $a$ is a positive real number and for every pair of real numbers $x$ and $y$. Suppose that $f(a)\neq0$. What is the value of $f(0)$? Hence or otherwise, prove that $f$ is an odd function.

**What I've done**: When I saw that equation, what springs to mind is to change the subject to $f(x) $. However, it's rather complicated and messy. Alternatively, I used differentiation and integration for both sides, to see whether it'll be easier for computation. However, I figured out $f$ is not assumed to be differentiable or continuous here.

The unsuccessful attempts make me wonder, how should I approach to this question? I'm currently confused and not knowing how to proceed. Any hints, approaches or answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

for $x=0$ and $y=0$ your equation becomes
$$
f(a)-f(a)=2f(0)f(0)
$$

Comment: Oh so a pair of real numbers $x$ and $y$ mean $x$ and $y$ are equal?

Comment: @ordinary No, the statement allows you to plug in any numbers for $x$ and $y$. E.g., with $x=7$ and $y=3$, you obtain $f(10+a)-f(4+4)=2f(7)f(3)$. But of course you are also allowed to plug in same values, such as $04 for both.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I see.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Substitute $y$ with $-y$. Then use that $f$ is either identically zero (and hence odd) or you  can pick $x$ such that division by $2f(x)$ is allowed. (We do not need that $f(a)\ne0$).

Comment: Nice hint for proving $f$ is odd!